# Grouping pairs of combination data based on given condition

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, grouping, combinations

Suppose I have a huge array of data and sample of them are :

```
x= [ 511.31, 512.24, 571.77, 588.35, 657.08, 665.49, -1043.45, -1036.56,-969.39, -955.33]
```

I used the following code to generate all possible pairs

```
Pairs=[(x[i],x[j]) for i in range(len(x)) for j in range(i+1, len(x))]
```

Which gave me all possible pairs. Now, I would like to group these `pairs` if they are within threshold values of -25 or +25 and label them accordingly.
Any idea or advice on how to do this? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly your problem, the code below should do the trick. The idea is to generate a dictionary whose keys are the mean value, and just keep appending data onto it:

```
import numpy as np #I use numpy for the mean.

#Your threshold
threshold = 25 
#A dictionary will hold the relevant pairs
mylist = {}
for i in Pairs:
    
    #Check for the threshold and discard otherwise
    diff = abs(i[1]-i[0])
    
    if(diff < threshold):
        #Name of the entry in the dictionary
        entry = str('%d'%int(np.mean(i)))
        
        #If the entry already exists, append. Otherwise, create a container list
        if(entry in mylist):
            mylist[entry].append(i)
        else:
            mylist[entry] = [i]
```

which results in the following output:

```
{'-1040': [(-1043.45, -1036.56)],
 '-962': [(-969.39, -955.33)],
 '511': [(511.1, 511.31),
  (511.1, 512.24),
  (511.1, 512.35),
  (511.31, 512.24),
  (511.31, 512.35)],
 '512': [(511.1, 513.35),
  (511.31, 513.35),
  (512.24, 512.35),
  (512.24, 513.35),
  (512.35, 513.35)],
 '580': [(571.77, 588.35)],
 '661': [(657.08, 665.49)]}
```

Comment: Yes, this is what I am looking for. Just one question. The mylist is 'dict' type. How can I convert this to some kind of array of a table where label represented by mean values and its corresponding grouping values?

Comment: I do not understand what you mean. The dictionary is essentially a table, whose entries are the keys.

Comment: I tried to run this code with different sets of data. But it is not able to do group the data based on threshold values that are efficient. Could you please relook at your code

Answer (score 0):

This should be a fast way to do that:

```
import numpy as np
from scipy.spatial.distance import pdist

# Input data
x = np.array([511.31, 512.24, 571.77, 588.35, 657.08,
              665.49, -1043.45, -1036.56,-969.39, -955.33])
thres = 25.0
# Compute pairwise distances
# default distance metric is'euclidean' which
# would be equivalent but more expensive to compute
d = pdist(x[:, np.newaxis], 'cityblock')
# Find distances within threshold
d_idx = np.where(d <= thres)[0]
# Convert "condensed" distance indices to pair of indices
r = np.arange(len(x))
c = np.zeros_like(r, dtype=np.int32)
np.cumsum(r[:0:-1], out=c[1:])
i = np.searchsorted(c[1:], d_idx, side='right')
j = d_idx - c[i] + r[i] + 1
# Get pairs of values
v_i = x[i]
v_j = x[j]
# Find means
m = np.round((v_i + v_j) / 2).astype(np.int32)
# Print result
for idx in range(len(m)):
    print(f'{m[idx]}: ({v_i[idx]}, {v_j[idx]})')
```

Output

```
512: (511.31, 512.24)
580: (571.77, 588.35)
661: (657.08, 665.49)
-1040: (-1043.45, -1036.56)
-962: (-969.39, -955.33)
```